# TTT - html and javascript

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="c1">-</td>
            <td id="c2">-</td>
            <td id="c3">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c4">-</td>
            <td id="c5">-</td>
            <td id="c6">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c7">-</td>
            <td id="c8">-</td>
            <td id="c9">-</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function crossCircle(){                                     
      if (this.id == "-")                                       
      {                                     
        document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = "X";                                       
      }                                     
}        

document.getElementById("c1").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c2").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c3").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c4").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c5").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c6").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c7").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c8").onlick = crossCircle;                                     
document.getElementById("c9").onlick = crossCircle;
```

I have this html and js, why is my table's "-" not being replaced by the string "X"? I am a bit confused. Additionally, can I have some tips / advice or example on how to implement the circle, so it takes turns and doesn't replace the X or O that's already in the box?

Answer (score 1):

The method is `.onclick` not `.onlick`. Also, in your `crossCircle()` method, you are checking if the **id** of the element is equal to '-' rather than the **value**. You probably want something like the following

```js
function crossCircle()                                      
{                                       
  if (this.innerHTML == "-")                                       
  {                                     
    this.innerHTML = "X";                                       
  }                                     
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, it works:) btw do you have a tip to how I can implement the O that takes turn?

Comment: You would need a way to store the current state (a.k.a. who's turn it is), then check what character should be set when you're updating the value of the clicked cell. If you need more help, you should probably ask a separate question. Also, there are tons of js tic-tac-toe tutorials online you could check out.

Comment: @DoveyDovel Feel free to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks